# Avoiding null checks

Tags: java

I'd like to avoid ternary expressions for null checking i.e. `return x == null ? null : return x.y;` So I want to return composite object of another object which might be null - in that case I'd like to simply return null. I'm looking for some utility method (Guava mby?) that would be shorter than ternary expression with null check.

Comment: try to use something called Assertions

Comment: Both Java8 and Guava introduce the type `Optional<T>`, which is what you need, I guess

Comment: @Arlind assertion isn't what I need since it'd throw error if x is null and it wouldn't be shorter syntax use.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov Unfortunately we stucked at Java 7, not sure when we'll update codebase to 8. Using Guava's Optional: `Optional.fromNullable(x.y);` where x is null raises NPE.

Comment: @ZZ5, shouldn't it be `Optional.fromNullable(x)`?

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov That's the problem - I need composite of x - y (x.y). Both can be null, however when I try to access y when x is null I get NPE. I wanted to avoid situation like this, I've tried to write some utility method, but I couldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache commons has `ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull()`.

See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html